# What is actually document in Document Database

Tags: database, metadata, document, orientdb

Actually I am new to Document Database and I understand what it does in form of relationships and so on. But I have a question regarding the document stoarge it self. I understand that Document Database such as OrientDB contains documents, which are records that describe the data in the document (meta data) in a form of JSON, XML and so on. However, I am not sure if the full text of a document can be also stored. All examples I saw store only the meta data about a document and not the document full text it self.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Paginated-Local-Storage.html) can help you, it is explained in detail all the part related to the saved data.

Comment: Thanks but this is not related to my specific question. I am interested to know whether the document designed/better to store only meta data or also it can store the full text document.